# workflows running slowly

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have a list with a workflow that runs for every item that is added or changed. I imported about 700 records in to the list via Microsoft Access. Immediately after the import only 100 or so items had a workflow status of Completed. The rest all say Starting.

It has now been almost 2 hours and there are still 400 items that say Starting.

How can I speed up this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a SP Workflow Postpone Threshold, and by default it's set at 15. You can raise this by using the `Set-SPFarmConfig` namespace in Powershell using the `WorkflowPostponeThreshold` parameter.

//The following powershell command raises the Workflow Postpone Threshold to 30

```
Set-SPFarmConfig -WorkflowPostponeThreshold 30
```

[SP 2010 Workflow Limitations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.14%29.aspx#Workflow)

[Set-SPFarmConfig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607962%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: That did it! I set it to 100 for a bit and everything cleared up. Thanks!